# how to save file in json with javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I write this code for saving data in json in javascript and the error is:

> **Uncaught TypeError:** `file.open` is not a function

```
var txtFile = "./tmp/test.txt";
var file = new File([""], txtFile);
var str = JSON.stringify("string");

file.open(); 
file.write(str);
file.close();
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Are you running this in nodejs or where?

Comment: Please elaborate your environment and context. Don't post vague questions.

Comment: Why did you think `File` has an `open` method?

Comment: in javascript envirenmont

Comment: You can't write files from the browser onto the local machine, if that's what you are trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this, maybe you can use it or see how it's made:

https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

Comment: Placing a link to a third party library with instructions of finding it for themselves is not an answer. Offer some more information on the details of how this library works and/or code samples to support your answer. A link is not valuable if the resource becomes no longer available.